# jQuery function not recognised on iPhone

Tags: jquery, iphone

I have a jQuery slideshow that works across all browsers and android devices, but when testing on an iPhone 4 it doesn't work.

Stripping it back to a simple in-page alert, jQuery still doesn't work on iPhone. Any suggestions as to what's going on here?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>

// works everywhere, except on iPhone
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
    alert('jQuery function');
});
</script>

// works
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert('js function');
</script>
```

Comment: This probably won't help, but I thought I'd ask whether or not it made a difference using the latest jQuery script?

Comment: Very strange. I highly recommend using <a href="http://phonegap.github.com/weinre/">Weinre</a> to debug this issue on the iphone simulator.

Comment: Thanks both, I'll give the debugger a go. Updating to jQuery 1.7.1 didn't resolve the issue. I've also tested this on a 3GS without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved. It appears jQuery 1.6.2 and greater isn't supported by Safari on iPhone. Using a cdn of version 1.4.2 solved the problem.